# Annoying notification that wont go away in kde plasma 5

Tags: 16.04, flash, notification, kde5, plasma-5

Every time i log into kde plasma 5 i get this annoying notification in my system tray. [image: flash notification]

If i click OK, it asks for my password and then tries to install it before ultimately failing to do so. I get this error message every single time:[image]

Clicking on the Details button do not show anything at all.

This thing happens only in plasma desktop. In unity or in cinnamon there are no such notifications. How do i get rid of this?

Comment: I'm assuming it might be added to your startup application you can try removing it from your startups if you have the system settings it should be located there

Comment: @RobGoss No there is no such thing enabled in the Startup settings. The only things enabled are screen locker, messenger, psensor, variety and whatsie

Comment: I notice the windows were you're getting the error message there's a detailed tab, click on that button it should tell you were that error is coming from and what packages is causing it. You have to remove ether a broken or outdated package

Comment: @RobGoss As i have said in the question description, clicking on the details button do not produce any result. I can click it as many times i like, but nothing comes out of it. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem. In synaptic package manager, under the *'Missing Recommends'* section, there is an entry called *'flashplugin-installer'*. I installed it and now that problem is gone.

Hope it helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for posting your results I'm sure it will help others

Comment: How to get rid of this notification without installing the Flash plugin?